# Makefile: error running 'make all'

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

When I run the same gcc command specified in my make all rule, I get no error. But when I run make all, I get a bunch of errors. Why is this happening?

Makefile:

```
all: program.c
      gcc -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include program.c -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib -lswscale -lavdevice -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lz -lm -lpthread -o program
```

Running the gcc command:

```
 (No error)
```

Running make all:

```
gcc -IOME/ffmpeg/include program.c -LOME/ffmpeg/lib -lswscale -lavdevice -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lz -lm -lpthread -o program
program.c:15:32: error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
program.c:16:32: error: libswscale/swscale.h: No such file or directory
program.c:17:34: error: libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory
program.c:19: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
program.c:24: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
program.c:95: error: expected ')' before '*' token
program.c:128: error: expected ')' before '*' token
program.c:201: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
program.c: In function 'main':
program.c:253: error: 'AVFrame' undeclared (first use in this function)
program.c:253: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
program.c:253: error: for each function it appears in.)
program.c:253: error: 'loaded_image' undeclared (first use in this function)
program.c:255: error: 'img_copy' undeclared (first use in this function)
program.c:255: error: 'AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24' undeclared (first use in this function)
program.c:256: error: 'current_frame' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: I think, in your **makefile** you have `gcc -IOME` instead of `gcc -I$HOME`

Comment: @PetrBudnik, no, it's just that `$H` isn't a `make` variable.

Comment: @CarlNorum Are you sure you can't use it the way @juanchopanza suggested? (I made a mistake not using `()` in my first comment).

Comment: @PetrBudnik - yeah, you can.  `$(HOME)` is the right thing, too.  `make` will expand it instead of the shell in that case.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yeah, I had to check one of my own **makefile**'s just to make sure - you got me wondering ;)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$HOME` expands as `OME` in your `make` environment.  If you want the shell to expand it, you need to escape it:

```
  gcc -I$$HOME/ffmpeg/include ...
```

What's happening to you now is that `make` is expanding `$H` to nothing, then using the rest of the line as-is.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference in using `$HOME` on the command line (shell) and using `$HOME` in a Makefile.

In a Makefile, you must surround the variable name with parenthesis, like

```
all: program.c
      gcc -I$(HOME)/ffmpeg/include program.c -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib -lswscale -lavdevice -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lz -lm -lpthread -o program
```

See [Basics of Variable References](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference) and [Variables from the Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment) for more.